# failed to create oob message?

Tags: objective-c, bonjour, gamekit

Hi  I'm trying to build a simple chat client between two ipod touches Just as a start to learning Bonjour.
I connect the two devices fine and everything seems like it should work. I can send the data with no problems (no error) , but When I should then receive the data  and I dont. When I look in the log, I see "GCKSessionEvent_IncomingOOBPacket: failed to create oob message" I've tried
Googling ever piece of that message looking for some answer but there are literally 0 results. I was hoping someone here might have an answer.

thanks

KC

Response to comment:

The three calls are

```
-(IBAction)SendMessage
{   
NSData* aData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[typeText.text dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self sendDataToPeers:aData];
}

-(void)sendDataToPeers:(NSData*)data
{
    NSError* err;
    BOOL didSend = [self.mySession sendDataToAllPeers:data withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:&err];
}

-(void) receiveData:(NSData*)data fromPeer:(NSString*)peer inSession:(GKSession*)session context:(void*)context
{
    NSString* text = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    self.displayText.text = text;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like somehow you are trying to send Out Of Band data to the other client.  What kind of calls do you use to send/receive the data?

Comment: Thanks Kenny, Im new to this site and had no idea how to make that happen. Way better formatting.

Comment: Slightly more info. About 4 times now during an attempted build Ive gotten this pop up box.

"Can't start debugger. CFSocketSetAddress returns error '-1'
Try rebooting your device and/or Macintosh."

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing iphone to iphone with Wifi and GKSession. After aborted sessions (aka debugging or crash) Bonjour (or GKsessions) seem to get confused and this same scenario happens to me.  With OS 3.x there was no message, just the hang.  With OS 4.x I get the message "GCKSessionEvent_IncomingOOBPacket...".  I have no idea what this means, but restarting the GKsession or reconnecting or sometimes just waiting solve the problem.  I suspect might be a buffer full on outbound data due to messed up peers/receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Kendrick, assuming you are using the 4.0 SDK, then you may be SOL on this. GKSession has a number of show-stopper bugs in the 4.0 SDK (crashes, errors, slowness) that were introduced recently. This message is due to one of them. I know because I was about to submit my GameKit app when they released 4.0 and now I'm waiting for 4.1 so I can submit it. The 4.1 Beta does fix a number of these issues, but it still doesn't work the way it worked on 3.1.3, sadly.